# Not knowing the destination of USB in CMD

Tags: batch-file, cmd, xcopy, autorun

I am trying to copy files from my USB drive to my PC automatically by using a batch file (.bat)

I know I can do something like that

```
xcopy "C:\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx.xxx" "C:\xxxx\xxx\xxxx\xxx.exe" /E /H /I
```

But I faced a little problem...

What if I don't know the exact letter of the drive, where the USB is inserted? How am I able to copy those files automatically? If this is possible, can someone please post a simple "xcopy" command from USB to PC.

Thanks!

Comment: What version of Windows are you running?

Comment: Windows 7 Ultimate x64

Comment: Drive letter of any drive (except for %SystemDrive%) can be fixed with Disk Management (run diskmgmt.msc). The assignment will survive reboot.

Answer (score 3):

Can you add a generic file to the root of the USB drive so you can test for it to discover the drive letter of the USB drive?  For instance, if you created a file called `USBDrive1` in the root of the USB drive, you could do something like this:

```
for %%i in (D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do if exist %%i:\USBDrive1 set USBDrive=%%i
```

Then you can use `%USBDrive%` for the drive letter in the rest of your batch file.  Like this:

```
xcopy %USBDrive%:\*.* C:\Some\Path ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer James L.

But wouldn't this be much easier if I dont even type the command for the drive letter? Simply because the batch file is executing on its destination, right? So that means nomather what is the drive letter the `xcopy` command should work?

I am talking something about this

`@ECHO OFF
XCOPY filename.extenstion c:\pastefolder /m /e /y`

Comment: @AdlerAdemov - That does make a difference.  I didn't realize the batch file was on the USB drive.  In that case, Ohad_E's answer is likely the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

Place your batch file in your USB drive using this syntax:

```
 xcopy %~d0\folder\*.* c:\target\   /E /H /I
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
set "USBDrive="
for /F "tokens=1,2" %%a in ('wmic logicaldisk get DeviceID^,DriveType') do if %%b equ 2 set USBDrive=%%a
if not defined USBDrive (
   echo USB not connected
) else (
   echo USB on drive %USBDrive%
)
```

Comment: That is a very useful way to identify drive types.  But what if there are multiple USB drives?  I suppose you could use the `wmic` command to find the USB drives, and then look for a file in the root of just those to find the one USB drive to copy from...  That would be more efficient than checking all of the drives from D to Z.

Comment: If could be two USB drives mounted (or two floppy disks, or two hard disks, etc) the standard way to identify a particular one may be via the label of the disk, that can be accessed via `vol` command.