# how to access a usb drive using its label and navigate with CMD

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I would like to know if it's possible to access a usb drive using its label, for example
I can navigate to the drive with PowerShell but I would like to know how to do something similar to this in CMD

```
$usbPath = Get-WMIObject Win32_Volume | ? { $_.Label -eq 'volumelabel' } | select name ; cd $usbPath.name
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22278424/62576

Comment: The command line interface to WMI is `wmic` so from your code `wmic path win32_volume get /format:csv` or `wmic path win32_volume get /format:list`. To be more precise on what is returned `wmic path win32_volume where "label='RECOVERY'" get /format:list`

Comment: I have a feeling however, that `%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe Path Win32_Volume` or using its alias `%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe Volume`, requires elevation for standard users.

Comment: It does not require elevation. It has a flaw that it initialises system files on first run. So once an admin has run it once unelevated users can use it. Not sure why this has not been fixed since at least Win 2000.

Comment: @Compo I left the alias out because I was showing how to convert the object from Powershell to command prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest, *and much quicker that loading [wmic](/questions/tagged/wmic)*, method would be to use the `VOL` command

[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)

```
For %G In (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z)Do @Vol %G: 2>NUL|%__AppDir__%find.exe /I "volumelabel">NUL&&CD /D %G:
```

[batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file)

```
@For %%G In (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
) Do @Vol %%G: 2>NUL | %__AppDir__%find.exe /I "volumelabel" >NUL && CD /D %%G:
```

Instead of just checking every possible drive letter, you could reduce that to only mounted drive letters by using `MountVol`:

From [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd):

```
For /F "Delims=\ " %G In ('"%__AppDir__%mountvol.exe 2>NUL|%__AppDir__%find.exe ":\""') Do @Vol %G 2>NUL|%__AppDir__%find.exe /I "volumelabel">NUL&&CD /D %G
```

From a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file)

```
@For /F "Delims=\ " %%G In ('"%__AppDir__%mountvol.exe 2>NUL|%__AppDir__%find.exe ":\""'
) Do @Vol %%G 2>NUL | %__AppDir__%find.exe /I "volumelabel" >NUL && CD /D %%G
```

---

If you still wanted to use [wmi](/questions/tagged/wmi) and you have sufficient privileges to use `Path Win32_Volume`, *(or its alias `Volume`)*, with it then…

From [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd):

```
For /F "Skip=1Tokens=2" %G In ('%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe Volume Where "Label='volumelabel'" Get DriveLetter^,Name 2^>NUL')Do @CD /D %G
```

And from a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```
@For /F "Skip=1 Tokens=2" %%G In (
    '%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe Volume Where "Label='volumelabel'" Get DriveLetter^,Name 2^>NUL'
) Do @CD /D %%G
```

Otherwise you could use `Path Win32_LogicalDisk`, *(or its alias `LogicalDisk`)* instead…

From [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd):

```
For /F "Skip=1Tokens=2" %G In ('%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe LogicalDisk Where "VolumeName='volumelabel'" Get DeviceID^,Name 2^>NUL')Do @CD /D %G
```

And from a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```
@For /F "Skip=1 Tokens=2" %%G In (
    '%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe LogicalDisk Where "VolumeName='volumelabel'" Get DeviceID^,Name 2^>NUL'
) Do @CD /D %%G
```

Comment: Another way to do this (at least in English): for /f %g in ('%__AppDir__%mountvol.exe ^| %__AppDir__%find.exe ":\"') do for /f "tokens=4" %h in ('dir %g ^|%__AppDir__%find.exe "USB"') do cd /d %h:\

Comment: Replace "USB" above with your drive label.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `wmic logicaldisk get name, volumename` to see all of the connected drives and their drive letters and then use `| <name>` to find your specified drive where  is the label for your drive. So in all you would do

```
for /f %%i in ('"wmic logicaldisk get name, volumename | find "DRIVENAME" "') do (set Driveletter=%%i) 
cd %Driveletter%
```