# Change directory to another disk without knowing disk label

Tags: windows, batch-file, raspberry-pi

I was trying automate modifing some files on another drive (boot files for raspberry pi). I want to add couple lines of text to config.txt and cmdline.txt but windows alwas mounts the boot drive with diffrent drive letter (label stays the same: "boot"). I need to change directory (in batch file) to rpi's boot drive (label: "boot"). Can you help?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61738542/how-to-access-a-usb-drive-using-its-label-and-navigate-with-cmd/61739493#61739493 I feel like the answers there are well-suited for your question

Answer (score 1):

On a regular Windows computer, you can use `wmic` for getting Windows configuration information, like this here:

```
wmic logicaldisk get description,caption
```

You might also use:

```
wmic logicaldisk list
```

In case this does not help, you might try the following:

```
wmic volume get label, name
```

Comment: I used this: "wmic logicaldisk get volumename,name", I need labels of disks not drive letters, also how can I use this info in batch file to change to disk with label "boot"?

Comment: Using a command output as a variable is a burden indeed in batchfiles, I can give you this reference to start with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359820/how-to-set-commands-output-as-a-variable-in-a-batch-file

Comment: As for the label, instead of "logicaldisk", you might try "volume", like `wmic volume get label, name`, is this what you're looking for?

Comment: @pacjo: I've adapted my answer accordingly. Please upvote or accept my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In order to determine the drive letter associated with the label `boot`, and change the current directory to the root of it, I would expect that a command such as this would perform the expected task:

```batch-file
@For /F "Tokens=2 Delims==:" %%G In ('%__APPDIR__%wbem\WMIC.exe Volume Where "Label='boot'" Get DriveLetter /Value 2^>NUL') Do @CD /D %%G:\
```

*Please note that, there is no functionality built into this single line [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) code, to cater for the possibility that you may have more than one attached volume, with the same label.*